# Capture first content paint, large content paint, first input delay metrics in Apache Annette or blazemeter

Tags: web, jmeter, blazemeter, core-web-vitals

How to capture the web vitals like first content paint, largest content paint, first input delay or any other metrics for performance tests executed in performance testing tools like Apache Jmeter or Blazemeter?

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Project](https://jmeter.apache.org/) main page:

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So with JMeter you can have only [TTFB](https://web.dev/time-to-first-byte/) metric which is known as [Latency](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) in JMeter world.

With regards to the other metrics you will need to take extra steps to get them:

- use an [APM tool](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for monitoring frontend metrics
- install [Web Witals](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) and use the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) to kick off a real browser, open the application under test and get the Web Vitals metrics via JavaScript